# I cant connect to the wifi even if there is internet connection

Tags: wi-fi, connection-issues

I cant connect to the wifi even if there is internet connection.The wifi icon is displayed on the notification bar(with range),and its shows connected tothe link too.i can access net on my pc(on which the modem is connected)but cant connect to any other external devices.i have tried it with various phones,tablets and laptops.but the result is same.please help me

Comment: I require some clarification here: 1) First, you mentioned that you can see Wifi icon with range in notification bar but cannot access internet. OK. Then you said *cant connect to any other external devices.i have tried it with various phones,tablets and laptops* -- do they show the same icon with bars but cannot access the internet, or they can't even connect to wifi at all?

Comment: I think you should [edit] and make bullet points like: 1) PC is connected to modem and can access internet, 2) Your device can see wifi icon with range but cannot access internet, 3) your other devices either cannot access the internet, or can't even connect to wifi at all (IDK which one is your case, please clear this out). // If your device can connect to wifi but not to internet, then use the word "access/can't access internet". If your devices cannot connect to wifi at all, then use "connect/can't connect to wifi".

Answer (score -1):

**DELETE HOSTS FILE**

For advanced users only. For rooted Android devices only.

- Open File Manager App.
- Browse to `root/system/etc`.
- Delete `hosts.txt` file